# Woocommerce product list issue with unwanted whitespace in sort order

Tags: sorting, woocommerce, product, removing-whitespace, gaps-in-visuals

There are missing products or “gaps” in our product listings. I’ve never seen this happen – it seems to be inadvertent.  Additionally, should we change the number of products per row to 4, it will not change.

This screenshot shows the issue, where the row near the bottom has just one thumbnail in the center. Sometimes it’s to the left/right.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11EGpqy7007Tz9APlEu8ponCoC183JTR9/view?usp=sharing

This is a category it's happening to:  https://5pointsfarmjax.com/product-category/fresh-produce/

The environment includes php 8.1, current wordpress, Aspen theme with WP Bakery and Ultimate addons.  I've deactivated each of the plugins, reset permalinks, reset cache. I don't see any related errors in the console (that I know of).

Any ideas on a fix?  I'm fresh out!

Comment: It took quite some time to discover, but Just by shortening the product title, the gap is gone and the table is perfect.:  https://5pointsfarmjax.com/product-category/fresh-produce/.  However (a) gaps still appear in other areas (b), it will not allow me to use a 4 column format and (c) grid only displays 2 columns when sidebar is activated using the shortcode here: 
 https://5pointsfarmjax.com/test/

Comment: To clarify:  It won't allow for a 4 column format on the *default* shop home page.   And it won't allow for 3 columns using *shortcode*.  If anyone knows a way to have woo styling perhaps *override* the theme's until there's a possible update, I'd sure appreciate it!